# Is there a way to create bullet lists in kivy / python?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is there a way to create bullet lists in the kv language?

like:

- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you make labels that contains the text you want. You can also add the dots before the sentence. But maybe a drop-down list could help? [Kivy Drop-Down List](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use unicode code points.

For Example  unicode of  bullet point(•) is \u2022

You can use following code snippet to  get desired output.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SampleApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Label(text="\u2022 bullet 1 \n\u2022 bullet 2 \n\u2022 bullet 3 \n ")

SampleApp().run()
```

or in kv file some thing like this ..

```
Label:
    text: '\u2022 bullet 1 \n\u2022 bullet 2 \n\u2022 bullet 3 \n'
```

Reference to Unicode characters : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you were looking for. However I ran into a similar issue, using '>' works well.

```
grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
label_1 = Label(text=' > Text 1')
label_2 = Label(text=' > Text 2')
grid.add_widget(label_1)
grid.add_widget(label_2)
```

Comment: • Why not use ascii bullet point? • https://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php